# Crashes in -[ANSAttributeDictionary initWithDictionary:]

Tags: google-fabric

We're seeing a large number of app crashes in the following. Does anyone have ideas on what might be the cause?

We see these crashes on all iOS versions we support (iOS 9 to 11). And they started relatively recently, around Dec. 12.

```
Crashed: io.answers.EventQueue (QOS: BACKGROUND)
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000000102467200

0
libswiftCore.dylib  
specialized _fatalErrorMessage(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 63112
1   libswiftCore.dylib  
static ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional._forceBridgeFromObjectiveC(_:result:) + 5184
2   libswiftCore.dylib  
protocol witness for _ObjectiveCBridgeable._bridgeToObjectiveC() in conformance <A> A! + 70672
3   libswiftCore.dylib  
bridgeAnythingNonVerbatimToObjectiveC(swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, bool) + 144
4   libswiftCore.dylib  
bridgeAnythingNonVerbatimToObjectiveC(swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, bool) + 200
5   libswiftCore.dylib  
_SwiftDeferredNSDictionary.bridgeEverything() + 58432
6   libswiftCore.dylib  
specialized _SwiftDeferredNSDictionary.enumerateKeysAndObjects(options:using:) + 30288
7   libswiftCore.dylib  
_SwiftDeferredNSDictionary.enumerateKeysAndObjects(options:using:) + 57856
8
libswiftCore.dylib  
@objc _SwiftDeferredNSDictionary.enumerateKeysAndObjects(options:using:) + 59092
9   udemy-mobile-ios    
-[ANSAttributeDictionary initWithDictionary:] + 4347003980
10  udemy-mobile-ios    
-[ANSCustomEvent attributesDictionary] + 4347045360
11  udemy-mobile-ios    
-[ANSCustomEvent dictionaryRepresentation] + 4347045140
12  udemy-mobile-ios    
-[ANSWriteEventOperation generateFormattedLogLineWithEvent:] + 4347021348
13  udemy-mobile-ios    
-[ANSWriteEventOperation initWithEvent:metadata:logFileUrl:] + 4347019544
14  udemy-mobile-ios    
__37-[ANSAnswersController enqueueEvent:]_block_invoke + 4347057216
15
Foundation  
__NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
25
libsystem_pthread.dylib 
start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. What version of Fabric and Crashlytics are you using in your app?

Comment: Happening with us too. On the latest version 1.3.6 of answers @MikeBonnell

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce it yet Doug, but if you can share a link to the crash I can dig in more.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sjx1gld3u9gdcgn/com.zomato.zomato_issue_25107_crash_98a62d15c9704e34b42db66b791980d2_DNE_0_v2.txt?dl=0 added stack trace here. @MikeBonnell

Comment: Thanks, we're taking a look.

Comment: @AnuragKabra Are you passing any custom attributes that are nil implicitly unwrapped optional values? This code snippet is an example that does that and crashes:


let nilImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional: String! = nil

let attrs: [String: Any] = [

    "key": nilImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional

]

Answers.logCustomEvent(withName: "test event", customAttributes: attrs)